# How to save a gmail draft with inline images?

Tags: python, image, email

I want to use a python script to save a gmail draft containing inline images and rendered html text, so that it can be checked before being sent manually.

It seems the cid protocol for attaching inline images doe not work when SENDING the email, even if the draft looks good.

```py
import pickle
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

import base64
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import mimetypes
import os
from apiclient import errors

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/']

def CreateDraft(user_id, message_body):
    """Create and insert a draft email.

    Args:
        * service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
        * user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
          can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
        * message_body: The body of the email message, including headers.

    Returns:
        Draft object, including draft id and message meta data.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server()
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    try:
        message = {'message': message_body}
        draft = service.users().drafts().create(userId=user_id, body=message).execute()    
        return draft
    except errors.HttpError as error:
        print ('An error occurred: %s' % error)
        return None

def CreateMessageWithAttachment(sender, to, subject, message_text, file_dir, filename):
    """Create a message for an email.

    Args:
      * sender: The email address of the sender.
      * to: The email address of the receiver.
      * subject: The subject of the email message.
      * message_text: The html text of the email message.
      * file_dir: The directory containing the file to be attached.
      * filename: The name of the file to be attached.

    Returns:
       An object containing a base64url encoded email object.
    """
    message = MIMEMultipart()
    message['to'] = to
    message['from'] = sender
    message['subject'] = subject

    msg = MIMEText(message_text,'html')
    message.attach(msg)

    path = os.path.join(file_dir, filename)
    content_type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(path)

    if content_type is None or encoding is not None:
        content_type = 'application/octet-stream'
    main_type, sub_type = content_type.split('/', 1)
    if main_type == 'text':
        fp = open(path, 'rb')
        msg = MIMEText(fp.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
        fp.close()
    elif main_type == 'image': #The only useful one for images
        fp = open(path, 'rb')
        msg = MIMEImage(fp.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
        fp.close()
    elif main_type == 'audio':
        fp = open(path, 'rb')
        msg = MIMEAudio(fp.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
        fp.close()
    else:
        fp = open(path, 'rb')
        msg = MIMEBase(main_type, sub_type)
        msg.set_payload(fp.read())
        fp.close()

    msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
    message.attach(msg)

    return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()).decode()}
```

This script creates a draft with an attached file. However, if the file is an image I would like it to be inline instead of an attachement...

Comment: I think the problem comes from the fact that I want to use local files for images, as using the URL of an internet image works just fine. (Just change a line or two, especially: src="image_URL" instead of src="cid:image{}")

Comment: The image should be attached to the message item if you want to use the `cid` in the HTML markup.

Comment: Isn't this the role of msg.attach(msgImage)?

Comment: I edited the script to make it (hopefully) more understandable